# Implement pie-chart with variable slice sizes in MPAndroidChart

Tags: android, charts, mpandroidchart

Thanks to my designer with great searching skills, I have to implement a pie chart in my android application like below.

[image]

I am using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) for charts elsewhere in the app.

So far, I haven't written code for the chart since I can't see any setters for altering slice sizes in the documentation.

Can someone point to any resource where anything like this is achieved or if it is not possible to do it with out-of-the-box version of the library?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi akshat, Have you found any way to achieve this kind of Pie chart?

Answer (score 2):

Does this kind of chart have a special name?
So basically the "value" is indicated not by the (angular) space the slices use like in a normal piechart, but by their height.

Currently it is **not possible** to create such a chart with MPAndroidChart by default. This would require significant modification of the library.
However, I am strongly considering to add such a feature in the future, because I really like the concept of this kind of chart.

Comment: Well, the man himself! Great work Philipp! :)

I don't know if we have special name for the chart. I can go ahead and create an issue for the same, if you think it can be part of the library. Although, I don't see many people using it since it looks like a graphic sugar to me. If we do go for the issue, I will also see if I can submit the fix for the issue myself (Depending on time I get from the client).